# Stack the div elements over each other

Tags: html, css

I have a website in which the layout looks something like this: (image below)

[image]

On the left panel, I have a div which displays a logo. I have another div which I want to put beneath the logo and so `divs` these have to be these stacked over each other. I tried fiddling with the z-indexes, but didn't quite get the rquired thing.
How can this be done?

Comment: Have you tried (re)positioning the divs? - otherwise, look into that... http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_positioning.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use also **position: absolute;** instead of relative for both elements when using z-index. Then it can make some distortion in your layout, so you can put the logo divs inside another relative div or use some other technique to fix it, however it must work when using position absolute and z-index. If it is still not working, check if some of your javascript is not interfering or if some other elements in your code have z-index, so it is causing the problems.

If using position absolute, do not forget to define **margin-left** and **margin-top**.

Comment: I did get the right result by using `position:absolute` but I was wondering whether absolute positioning of say top: 30px) will look fine on all devices/browsers? Is this the correct way of doing it?

Comment: use clear: both; and it should be fine in older browsers like ie6 if you have any issues

Comment: or clear: left; or clear: right;     more here: http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/css-asylum/the-ie6-absolute-positioning-bug-15285

Answer (score 2):

If `z-index` is not working for you try nesting the logo `<div>` in a wrapper `<div>` something like this

```
<div> <!--div container to hold the logo div-->
 <div><!--Logo div--></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Reference:** [**jsFiddle Logo Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/efLz5/)

**Status Update:** [**jsFiddle Logo Demo Just Border Version**](http://jsfiddle.net/efLz5/2/)

The above jsFiddle has ***extensive notes*** in the **CSS Section** so you can understand how to setup your specific Logo.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="logoHolder">
    <div id="logoContent">
      <div id="logoImage"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#logoHolder {
    width: 296px;
    height: 296px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 3px solid red;
}

#logoContent {
    width: 256px;
    height: 256px;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#logoImage {
    background-image:url(http://img841.imageshack.us/img841/4718/securitysealred256x256.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-color: aqua;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This looks slick to me and I was also able to get the right result by using `position:absolute` but I was wondering whether absolute positioning of say top: 30px) will look fine on all devices/browsers? Is the absolute positioning also the correct way of doing it?

Comment: Feel free to "update" my jsFiddle and post a revised link here for me to comment on.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve but try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/morgi/Wyetf/4/), adapting the values to your layout

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `margin` property, as shown in your image. If you put `margin-left` as a negative value for the right-side div, then the right-side div will move below/above the logo div.

Comment: The logo div and the new div are both in the sidebar panel which has a width of 220px. So, the logo and the new div do not come in a single line. Can I still use this margin-left property?

Comment: yes u might be able to..u will have to deal with margin property